# Supplying a column value from the library name

Tags: list, column-data

The value of a column is the name of the library in which the document is being inserted. Users are objecting to supplying a value when the value is already known.

Seems to me there are two responses to this: remove the column (and rely upon the document library name) or automatically choose the library name from the dropdown of library names. If the latter, how might that be done (without code)?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this with a Workflow in SharePoint Designer, which is triggered when the document is added to the library, and sets a field (your metadata field) to the name of the current list.

Comment: The problem is that one must create the library first. So, you can't tack on a workflow. There would need to be a process that includes: 1, library creation; 2, insertion of library name into list.

So far as I can see, Designer has no library creation activity. Besides, there are currently 27 libraries. If workflow is to be used, I suspect it will have to be the VS independent sort.

Thank you for the response...

Comment: You can attach a Workflow to a content type or create a Site Workflow (in SP2010), but this may definitely have to be done in VS.